# How to use GMLib from cadetill?

Tags: c++, gmlib, c++builder-xe6

I'm new to GMLib from cadetill and use C++ Builder XE6, I am able to display map already but just the map.

Now I'm trying to use the `TLatLang`, but I don't know how to use it.. what is the correct way to declare and initialize. because I would like to zoom into points.

I use

```
TLatLang *latlng;
map->ZoomToPoints(latlng, 16);
```

But give an error:

> Cannot convert TLatLng * to TLatLng * *' and Type mismatch in
>   parameter 'Points' (wanted 'TLatLng' * *', got TLatLng *)

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Got it...

Just use

GMMapName->RequiredProp->Zoom = numOfZoom;